# Unable to load the requested class: Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-library

I want to use pagination in my index page. So I used like following code in my project

```
class Transactions extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(array("Transaction"));
}

public function index()
{
    $cond = array();
    if($_POST){
        $cond = $this->input->post();
    }

   // load Pagination library
    $this->load->library('pagination');
```

It's work fine in my localhost, but when I upload this in live server, here show the following error..

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to load the requested class: Pagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de4XA.png)

- php v7.2
- codeigniter v3.1.11

Please anyone help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: did you check if Pagination.php exists in sytem/libraries?

Comment: yes, I was checked, it's available here @Vickel

Comment: with capital "P" ?

Comment: yes, like that > system/libraries/Pagination.php

Comment: And I also try > $this->load->library('Pagination'); this  way, but same error

Comment: I'd try to make a fresh, new installation of CI, then add manually your controller, views and models and see if this error continues to happen

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue.